# R - Saving every dataframe in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

I have this list of dataframes:

```
set.seed(1)
S1 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,30,rep=TRUE)))
S2 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,34,rep=TRUE)))
S3 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,21,rep=TRUE)))
S4 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,26,rep=TRUE)))
df_list1 = list(S1 = S1, S2 = S2, S3 = S3, S4 = S4)

set.seed(2)
S1 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,30,rep=TRUE)))
S2 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,34,rep=TRUE)))
S3 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,21,rep=TRUE)))
S4 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,26,rep=TRUE)))
df_list2 = list(S1 = S1, S2 = S2, S3 = S3, S4 = S4)

set.seed(3)
S1 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,30,rep=TRUE)))
S2 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,34,rep=TRUE)))
S3 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,21,rep=TRUE)))
S4 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,26,rep=TRUE)))
df_list3 = list(S1 = S1, S2 = S2, S3 = S3, S4 = S4)

set.seed(4)
S1 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,30,rep=TRUE)))
S2 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,34,rep=TRUE)))
S3 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,21,rep=TRUE)))
S4 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,26,rep=TRUE)))
df_list4 = list(S1 = S1, S2 = S2, S3 = S3, S4 = S4)

df_list = list (df_list1, df_list2, df_list3, df_list4)
names(df_list) = c("AB_df", "BC_df", "DE_df", "FG_df")
```

I want to save every single dataframe in this list (by write.table). I started to make a list of every single df-name:

```
level1 = paste("df_list", names(df_list), sep = "$")
samples = names(df_list[[1]])
df_names = paste(rep(level1, each = length(samples)), samples, sep = "$")
```

My idea is now to loop though this list and save the dataframe with write.table and automatically assign a name.

But my problem is that `df_names[i]` is a character and I cant use it as a df-path. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd flatten the list:

```
flatlist <- unlist(df_list, recursive = FALSE)
for (n in names(flatlist)) write.csv(flatlist[[n]], sprintf("%s.csv", n))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works already. Is there any way that I can seperate the AB_df and the S1 with an underscore and not with a dot? And I also want to have a .dat file, not .csv

Comment: Of course, just adapt the code to your specifics. You can use `gsub` to replace characters. The dot is hard-coded in `unlist`.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a nested for-loop as follows:

```
for(i in 1:length(df_list)){
  for(idx in 1:length(df_list[[i]])){
    write.table(df_list[[i]][[idx]],paste0("your_location",names(df_list[i]),"_",names(df_list[[i]][idx]),".csv"))
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thx, I get an error: Error in length(lst) : object 'lst' not found

Comment: @Mr.Spock, I just realised I changed the outer loop and forgot to change inner contents, let me know if it still an issue.